# Please make me sure about copy mode of autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

I Just need some confirmation with you guys!

I have 3000 rows and my macro must copy all the contents from, 1500 to 2500 rows to other sheet, The condition is, I have set an autofilter to the sheet, Now some cells are invisible, so the sheet shows us only filtered rows,So some of the rows from 1500 to 2500 are invisble due to autofilter mode. and now my macro must copy all the contents from, 1500 to 2500 rows, even though if the rows are invisible due to auotfilter.

I just did normal copy paste operation on the filtered sheet and it copied all the rows from 1500 to 2500  which are invisible also, is that how it works ? copy , paste operation copies all the cells even though when filters  are set ? I just wanted to make sure because yesterday, it copied only filtered rows and today , it copied all the rows, so im just bit confused

I have googled it , but all i found is copy visible cells special type for autofilter mode. not exactly to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a filter active and select complete visible rows x..y you will notice not a single flashing frame repersenting a single range, but multiple flashing boxes .... and indeed the manual Ctrl-C / Ctrl-V action will copy only the visible rows.

For a VBA code it's different. Try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim SR As Range ' source range

    ' each cell of the Autofiltered range which is visible
    For Each SR In ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ' rows between 1500 and 2500
        If SR.Row >= 1500 And SR.Row <= 2500 Then
            ' do the needfull 
            Debug.Print SR.Row
        End If
    Next SR
End Sub
```

Kind regards

Comment: I explained very clearly I need all the date not just visible cells but thanks for your help

Comment: so you just rewrite the For Each to `For Each SR In ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Cells`